# How to select data by category_id that have comma spread?

Tags: mysql

I have books data like this
I am trying to select books by category_id

for example

I have checkbox that target to category_id
I check category_id = 1

and I using where like %1%
result should be book_id 1,3,5
but book_id 14,18 also came

if I check category_id 1 and 8
result shoud be book_id 3

```
+---------+-------------+
| book_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |         1,2 |
|       2 |          14 |
|       3 |         1,8 |
|       4 |          18 |
|       5 |         1,2 |
|       6 |          11 |
+---------+-------------+
```

I don't like storing data like this but I can not change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, you should normalize the database. Storing comma separated values is not a scale-able solution. So ideally, your table should have one-to-many rows for `book_id` to `category_id`

So, the table should look like:

```
+---------+-------------+
| book_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |         1  |
|       1 |         2  |
|       2 |         14 |
|       3 |         1  |
|       3 |         8  | 
...
```

---

In your denormalized case, you can use [`Find_in_Set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT book_id 
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', category_id) > 0
```

Comment: Agree.. Storing data with multiple value in one column are not how database work..